# Add aria-hidden to Title element

Tags: sapui5, wai-aria

I am trying to make a business critical SAPUI5 application more accessible using screen readers by adding ARIA labels and landmarks. One issue is that some SAPUI5 elements such as sap.m.Title's without text have been used (abused) for layout purposes. I would like to add the aria-hidden attribute or a SAPUI5 analogue to these Title elements. But I can't figure out how to do this. I would like to change

```
<Title text="" class="title" />
```

into

```
<Title aria-hidden="true" text="" class="title" />
```

But setting aria-hidden on the Title like this seems to be invalid. How would I go about setting a standard HTML attribute on a SAPUI5 control?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Joshua

Comment: Hi Joshua. I’m surprised you want to hide it entirely. If it has been abused for layout purposes, I’m assuming that its role should be corrected instead, which you can do by assigning `role="paragraph"`. Is hiding the text completely what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just checked the SAP UI documentation, and apparently ARIA attributes are fully supported. What do you mean it is invalid?

Comment: Hi, Andy. I want to hide the text because the title doesn't contain any (which is mostly why I find it abusive). We discovered though that setting the CSS visibility to hidden automatically seems to add the aria-hidden attribute in SAPUI5. It's a very ad hoc solution but enough for us.
Can you provide a source for how all ARIA attributes are set in SAPUI5? Because SAPUI5 elements in controls do need to have these as properties and most don't have all (at least according to the API documentation)

Comment: Hoi. It seems weird to me that a library would apply attributes depending on styling. But of course there are some CSS properties that will hide any element from assistive technology, just as `aria-hidden` would. `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` are among them. Does this link help? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/ff7cab1f271a4181a86e5aa5c2f8d421

Comment: I was surprised too but this is in fact how it works. You can see it in the developer console. The link doesn't really help for this specific case but I just think SAPUI5 does a lot of accessibility stuff automatically. That's great of course unless you do weird things ... I'm going to leave it be for now and advocate for better general practices in the future (working with instead of against the framework)

Comment: Alright, good luck with that!